# What is the range of $ \ f(x,y)=\left( (\cos x+2) \cos y, \ (\cos x+2) \sin y , \ \sin x \right) \ $

Tags: real-analysis

If $ \ f: D=[-\pi, \pi] \times [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ , then

What is the range of $ \ f(x,y)=\left( (\cos x+2) \cos y, \ (\cos x+2) \sin y , \ \sin x \right) \ $ ?

**Answer:**

$ -1 \leq \cos x \leq 1 \\ \Rightarrow 1 \leq \cos x+2 \leq 3 \\ \Rightarrow -1 \leq (\cos x+2) \cos y \leq 3 \  \ on \ \ D \ $

Similarly,

$ 0 \leq (\cos x+2) \sin y \leq 3 \ \ on \ \ D \ $

and

$ 0 \leq \sin x \leq 1 \ \ on \ \ D \ $

Thus the range of $ \ f(x,y) \ $ is the set $ \ S=\{(x,y,z): -1 \leq x \leq 3 , \ 0 \leq y \leq 3 , \ 0 \leq z \leq 1 \} \ $

**Am I right ?**

**Help me out**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

$$  \ S=\{(x,y,z): -3 \leq x \leq 3 , \ -3 \leq y \leq 3 , \ -1 \leq z \leq 1 \} \ $$

Comment: At least$$((\cos x+2)\cos y)^2+((\cos x+1)\sin y)^2+\sin^2x=5+4\cos x\in[1,9],$$it cannot be the box described here.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco note that $\ f: D=[-\pi, \pi] \times [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ and your range is in  $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I didn't restrict the choice of $x$ and $y$ when summing the squares of each component. Or could you find $(x,y)\in[-π,π]^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(0,0,0)$?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco But for $x=0$ and $ y=\pi/2 f(x,y)=(0,3,0)$ for $ x=0 $and $y=0 f(x,y)=(3,0,0)$ the range I've given doesn't mean that you reach those value at a same point, it'is  abox wich contains the range. Is this the problem? How would you express the range?

Comment: Range is a synonym for image.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco The range I've given are correct fro each component, dou you agree? How would you express the range?

Comment: If it's written as $S_x=\{x\mid -3\leqslant x\leqslant3\}$, $S_y=\cdots$, $S_z=\cdots$, it's all right. However, here it's written as a single set in $\mathbb R^3$, which ignores the correlation between each component and contains extra points that are not in $f(D)$.